# Dual boot - ubuntu slow download speed

Tags: dual-boot, wireless

I just installed dual-boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04).
On Windows I have download speed like `~60 Mbit/s`
on Ubuntu it looks like this:

`Download: 0.71 Mbit/s`

I tried both: Home WiFi and also mobile hotspot (works the same in both cases)

None of solutions that I found worked for me.

Some info:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

@Update 1:
`lspci -knn`:
https://pastebin.com/SGq59AzG

@Update 2:
`lsusb` and `lspci` results:
https://pastebin.com/0Y8v36xN

**SOLUTION:**
Looks like I fixed this. This helped me: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2378849
Thanks @GabrielaGarcia for help. It's still not as fast as on windows but speed is good enough (`Download: 25.77 Mbit/s`).

Comment: The problem seems to be with the WiFi - and the question tagged with wireless - and yet you posted the information about the Ethernet (LAN) device? Also "home WiFi" or "mobile hotspot (WiFi)" would predictably give the same result. Do you notice the same problem with a cabled connection? If not (or for completeness) please [edit] and post the results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia result of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is nothing. I don't have posibility to connect PC using Ethernet cable. 
I updated post with `lspci -knn` result

Comment: *I don't have posibility to connect PC using Ethernet cable* So, as commented before, the information about a device you aren't using is... Useless. About the WiFi, is it internal or USB?  For the former try `lspci` without arguments and for the latter `lsusb`.

Comment: I using usb wifi card: TPLINK model: `TL-WN823N`. I don't see this device in `lsusb` results. Results in Update 2.

Comment: Model isn't really relevant, the chipset inside is. If it works, good or bad, it **must** be listed with `lsusb`, look for something mentioning "network", "wireless", etc. That's the **only** information that matters to eventually give you a meaningful answer.